# Center horizontally and/or vertically with 9 patch in Android

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, nine-patch

I can't find a topic talking about my problem which seems to me standard ... And that make me think it is not possible. But I give a try.

I have a RelativeLayout with a 9 patch background (which contain a content area).

Is that possible to center horizontally and/or vertically a TextView inside this RelativeLayout in relation to the content area ?

Comment: yes.can u pls post ur xml file??

Comment: It's Possible..but not without your XML..:)

Comment: I can't now, u have to wait 7 hour because i'm new... and xml in comment is ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this layout file will do the task

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the 9-patch image i used is

[image]

Comment: I'm almost sure I tried with gravity="center". Maybe i had miss it .. thanks!

Comment: I was having problems with relative layout and centerinparent / vertical / horizontal ignoring content area. This was a solution to that problem, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The top padding and the bottom padding is different.

Comment: @Henk please post the issue that you are facing