# Unable to align text after adding 9-patch as button background

Tags: android, button, background, nine-patch

I have a button on which text need to be aligned at center horizontally. Gravity works fine when the button is without the 9 Patch as a background. But as soon I add a 9 patch as a back ground the gravity shifts towards left and text refuses to budge no matter what gravity is set to.

I have tried setting padding to 0dip, -1px, @null as suggested on some other threads. None of them worked. I am changing background from within the code also using setBackgroundResource() as my requirements are pinned to API level 8, so other methods to set background is not an option. Also I can't use selector list to do this because I need that button to be in selected state (Like a toggle button).

Any inputs ?

Comment: Sounds like it wouldn't be a bad idea to post the 9 patch, or at least show a screenshot of what it looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to set padding to 0 after each time I set background, programmatically ! That solved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It is because in your 9-patch image you have assigned content area(see right bottom part).

Generally Right and Bottom part are for content padding *(optional)* so if you want to set padding via programming then don't manipulate Bottom and Right area of 9 patch.

[image]

Comment: I will verify this. Thanks for visual explanation.

Comment: According to this link http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ it is used to dictate fill area. This is getting confusing.

Comment: Link information is also correct, but they used different terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to this problem: [Center horizontaly and/or verticaly with 9 patch in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502005/center-horizontaly-and-or-verticaly-with-9-patch-in-android)

It uses `RelativeLayout` with 9-patch background and `TextView` put inside. You can then format and align text as you like without breaking 9-patch marigins and padding.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `android:padding="0dp"` to the `Button` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check and assign 9-patch image content area for EVERY state of that button's background.

I once forgot to set 9-patch image content area for pressed state of button, which somehow lead to wired padding behavior in normal state.